# Multiple rewritecond with different variables

Tags: apache-2.4, rewritecond

I am trying to match on two different things in a single request to proxy a request to a different server.

My rewrite conditions are:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (token=.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (lb[1-4]\.domain\.com\:(\d+))
```

My problem is that I would assume that %1 would refer to the first group of the first condition (token=xxxxx) and %2 would refer to the first group of the second condition (lb1.domain.com:8080). This is not happening and as per the log, it appears that the group of the first condition is completely lost (%1 is not token=xxx but rather lb1.domain.com:8080) and %2 is actually just the port number (so group #2 of the second condition).

Is there any way to ensure that I have access to the groups in both conditions?

Thanks